# XML to XML transformation with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and want to transform a XML to another XML.The required input and output format are as below,

Input XML

```
<record>
<fields>
<fieldname>"Name"</fieldname>
<fieldvalue>"ABCD"</fieldvalue>
<fieldname>"Age"</fieldname>
<fieldvalue>"22"</fieldvalue>
<fieldname>"Country"</fieldname>
<fieldvalue>"India"</fieldvalue>
</fields>
</record>
```

Required output XML,

```
<record>
<Name>"ABCD"</Name>
<Age>"22"</Age>
<Country>"India"</Country>
</record>
```

The **fieldname** is constant whereas **fieldvalue** are dynamic.How can this be realised using XSLT.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by *Vebbie* works due to a weird characteristics of
`xsl:value-of` in **XSLT 1.0**, namely even if the XPath expression returned
**multiple** nodes, the value to output is taken from the **first** node only.

This solution will not work in **XSLT 2.0**, where `xsl:value-of` outputs values of
**all** nodes found.

To make the script to output only the **first** following sibling, the XPath
expression must be supplemented with `[1]` (works also in **XSLT 1.0**).

Another detail is that in version **2.0** `replace` function is supported,
so you don't need *StringUtils* namespace.

So if you can use version **2.0**, my proposition is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="record/fields">
    <record>
      <xsl:for-each select="fieldname">
        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="replace(.,'&quot;','')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::fieldvalue[1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </record>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/nbiCsZa

## Edit

Even in **XSLT 1.0** you can do in this case without *StringUtils* namespace.
Instead of `str:replace`, you can call `translate` (supported in version
**1.0**), so the respective instruction should be changed to:

```
<xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="translate(.,'&quot;','')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **XSLT 1.0**, then it can be achieved as following:

**Note:** Here `replace()` from `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` is used to remove quotes appearing in `<fieldname>`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:str="xalan://org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"
exclude-result-prefixes="str">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="record/fields">
    <record>
        <xsl:for-each select="fieldname">
            <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="str:replace(.,'&quot;','')" />
            <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::fieldvalue" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </record>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: No, that's not an XSLT 1.0 answer. It will work only if your processor happens to support the (rather obscure) extension function.

Comment: Agreed but as far as the processor is not defined by the op the incorrectness cannot be claimed.